# mailto attachments in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-10, mailto

I have a question about mailto attachments (**Windows Store Apps, C#**).

Previously it was not possible to add attachments to **mailto** in Windows 8.1.

Is it possible to add attachments to **mailto** in **Windows 10**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage` class. It lets you add attachments.

[Read more on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.aspx)